# Python Logging: How can I determine when a handler was added?

Tags: python, logging

Sometimes I have multiple handlers attached to a given logger, but I only want one because the logs show up as duplicate lines.

I would like to know what code or module actually added the handler so I can turn them on/off.

The LogRecord class has a lot of info on where the record itself was added, but is there equivalent information for when the handler was added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monkeypatch the [`Logger.addHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler) method, e.g.

```
def monkeypatch_logging():
    import logging
    add_handler_orig = logging.Logger.addHandler

    def _addHandler(self, hdlr):
        import traceback
        traceback.print_stack()
        add_handler_orig(self, hdlr)

    logging.Logger.addHandler = _addHandler
```

Put the code somewhere near the entrypoint so it runs early enough, e.g.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    monkeypatch_logging()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('hello world')
```

will output:

```
  File "spam.py", line 18, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1823, in basicConfig
    root.addHandler(h)
  File "spam.py", line 10, in _addHandler
    traceback.print_stack()
INFO:root:hello world
```

The stacktraces will show you where `Logger.addHandler` was invoked.